# Symfony LDAP invalid credentials

Tags: symfony, authentication, ldap, forms-authentication

I keep getting an 'Invalid credentials' error when testing LDAP authentication with Symfony even though my email and my password should be correct. Is there any reason as to why this could be happening?

Twig:

```
    {% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {% if error %}
        <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

        <button type="submit">login</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

My controller:

```
 /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     * @param Request $request
     * @param AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils
     * @return Response
     */
    public function login(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
    {
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();


        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', array(
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
        ));
    }
```

services.yaml

```
services:
    Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap:
        arguments: ['@Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter']

    Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter:
        arguments:
            - connection_string: 'xxx'
              options:
                  protocol_version: 3
```

security.yaml

```
main:
            anonymous: lazy
            form_login_ldap:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
                service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                dn_string: 'ou=xxx,ou=xxx,ou=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=de'
                query_string: '(&(cn={username})(memberOf=cn=xxx,ou=xxx,ou=xxx,ou=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx))' 
                search_dn: 'uid=adminUser,ou=xxx,ou=xxx,ou=xxx,ou=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xx' 
                search_password: 'xxx'
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why first advice would be to try to connect the ldap by using the ldap PHP functions. Once it's Ok, you should have the correct values to put in the dn_string, query_string, search_dn and search_password parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The thing is, you must not be able to reach your LDAP because of a bad defintion in security.yaml and services.yaml. What I did in order to be sure that I have the right credentials to get to my ldap is this command in a terminal:

```
ldapsearch -x -LLL -h example.com -D "ldap_username@example.com" -w "ldap_password" -b "DC=example,DC=com"
```

ldap_username is the account that will be used to get the info from your LDAP and the ldap_password the password of the account. The account needs to be able to read info from your LDAP.
And if you get a result with your ldap user then it's good! otherwise you don't have the right credentials.